# Pass AJAX Variable to PHP and displaying MySQL results after selection from Dynamic Dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem passing a variable selected from a dynamic drop dropdown to a PHP file.  I want the PHP to select all rows in a db table that match the variable. Here's the code so far:

select.php

---

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#category").change(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#type").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
        var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');

        if(cat>0 && type>0)
        {
            var result = $("select#type option:selected").html();
            $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'display.php',
            data: {'result': myval},
            });



        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
    <form id="select_form">
        Choose a category:<br />
        <select id="category">
            <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
        </select>
    <br /><br />
    Choose a type:<br />
    <select id="type">
         <option value="0">choose...</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <?php include "display.php"; ?>

    <div id="result2"></div>         
</body>
</html>
```

select.class.php

---

```
<?php
class SelectList
{
protected $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DbConnect();
    }

    protected function DbConnect()
    {
        include "db_config.php";
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect     to the database");
        mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function ShowCategory()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM profession";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $category = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $category .= '<option value="' . $row['id_cat'] . '">' . $row['prof_name'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $category;
    }

    public function ShowType()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM specialties WHERE id_cat=$_POST[id]";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
        $type = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $type .= '<option value="' . $row['id_type'] . '">' . $row['sp_name'] . '</option>';
        }
        return $type;
    }



}

$opt = new SelectList();
?>
```

And here's the display.php that I want the variable passed to.  This file will select the criteria from the db and then print the results in select.php.

```
<?php


class DisplayResults
{
protected $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DbConnect();
    }

    protected function DbConnect()
    {
        include "db_config.php";
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
        mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function ShowResults()

    {

        $myval = $_POST['result'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM specialities WHERE 'myval'=sp_name";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
           echo "<table border='1'>";
           echo "<tr><th>id</th><th>Code</th></tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['sp_name'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['sp_code'];
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
            echo "</table>";
        //} 
        }
        return $category;
    }

}

$res = new DisplayResults();
?>
```

I'd really appreciate any help.  Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Link to db diagram:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeqVX.jpg

The first dropdown draws from the profession table, the second from the specialties table.  What I'd like to do is to display all of the rows in the jobs table that match the specialty selected in the dropdown box.  This will require the result from the variable (result) from the dropdown to be converted into the spec_code that is in the job table.  Not sure exactly how to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just want to outline some points about following block of code:

1. where did you defined **myval**
2. data: `{'result': myval}`: result not require any quota change it to data: `{result: myval}`
3. why you need to get HTML from selected options? it's better to send option values the change

`$("select#type option:selected").html();`

to

`$("select#type option:selected").val();`

```
if(cat>0 && type>0)
{
    var result = $("select#type option:selected").html();
    $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'display.php',
    data: {'result': myval},
    });
}
```